# Mass Update Views

Tags: list-view

Is there a way to mass update a bunch of views at the same time (add/remove columns to **all** views in a particular list)? We have a significant number of views, so it would be nice if we could update a bunch of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK SharePoint UI does not allow this but you could write a simple app to change your views. Check sample from [Programmatically create a view (custom view) of a list and change the view](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sowmyancs/programmatically-create-a-view-custom-view-of-a-list-and-change-the-view) below:

```
SPSite oSite = new SPSite([Site URL]);// [Site URL] change it to your sharepoint site URL
SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["shared documents"];  
SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oList.Views;
 
            string strViewName = "MyCustomView";
 
            System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields =
            new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
 
            viewFields.Add("Name");
            viewFields.Add("Type");
         
            string query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Name\"/>" +
                "<Value Type=\"Text\">mysample</Value></Eq></Where>";// here you can filter your items using the selected
                                                                         item in the dropdownlist
            oViewCollection.Add(strViewName, viewFields, query, 100, true, false);
 
 oWeb.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I had a feeling this was the only way.